# Calculate the area covered by a polygon in a google map in an Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I've got a series of `Location` / `GeoPoint` objects that form a polygon in my Android app. I wonder if there's any way to calculate the area covered by it.

So far I'm thinking about setting up a web service that, when posted the list of coordinates, uses the JS Google Maps API v3 to calculate the area. But there might be a way of doing this easily with some feature from Android I don't know about, natively.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037083/calculating-area-of-a-polygon-drawn-on-google-map

Comment: Yeah I had already checked that out, but I'm looking for a solution specific to Android (which, as far as I know, doesn't have Google Maps API v3 implemented)

Comment: David: yes, look at [this](https://gist.github.com/fdansv/6579158). You'll need [this library](http://www.jstott.me.uk/jcoord/). Sorry if the code contains dependencies and stuff, it's a project from long ago.

Comment: @fdansv what is the unit of the calculated area?

Comment: square metres if I remember correctly

Comment: I posted a method doing this here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16210785/891479

Comment: Hi. Do you remember how you got the vertices of the polygons? Looking for an answer to find vertices of a polygon on google maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method doing this is posted in following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16210785/891479

This is based on following formula:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon

Principle of plolygon area calculation using this formula:

http://maruzar.blogspot.com/2011/12/irregular-and-regular-polygon-area-by.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself, the way to calculate any polygn area knowing the corrdinates is explained in [Polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon).

You can find a more comprehensive explanation in [How to Calculate the Area of a Polygon](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon) under the topic `Irregular Polygons`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone, there is a very good answer in this thread:
[Calculate the area of a polygon drawn on google maps in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838287/calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-drawn-on-google-maps-in-an-android-application)

The answer from Marian Paździoch:

> There's already a [library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeArea(java.util.List)) for that.
>
> ```
> import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;
>
> //...
>
> List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
> latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893728, -8.491865));
> latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893550, -8.492479));
> latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893216, -8.492224));
> latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893404, -8.491598));
> Log.i(TAG, "computeArea " + SphericalUtil.computeArea(latLngs));
> ```