# Android calculate the area of polygon

Tags: android, polygon, android-maps-v2, area

I have successfully drawn the polygon in **Google map-V2** but my requirement is to calculate the area of that polygon, which is drawn on a map. I had also tried searching in Google, but I am not getting any API or other way to calculate the area of a polygon.

Please suggest me how can I calculate the **area of polygon** in Google map-v2?

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Have you checked out the code in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16210785/336557)?

Comment: Its a grateful, Thank u very much Mahm00d working correctly

Answer (score 1):

There's a lib for that already [computeArea](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeArea(java.util.List)).